# How do I make visible the menu in the composition section in After Effects where I can choose wireframe view?

Tags: after-effects

I need to toggle the wireframe option in the composition section but I'm missing the icons in the squared section in the image. How do I get these button icons so I can toggle the wireframe section? I tried toggling all of the menu bar options but can't seem to find the right one. Screenshot is from a youtube tutorial where the button icons that I'm looking for are visible.

[image: screenshot of menu bar in composition menu]

below is screenshot of what I see on my screen:
[image]

Comment: That’s a weird one. I can’t see any way to hide those controls. Can you share a photo of your screen? Is it possible you’re not looking at the composition viewer, but a source viewer in the same location?

Comment: Updated the question with a screengrab of my own After Effects screen. what is a source viewer by the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The toggle wireframe icon is this:

[image]

It is visible in your top image here:

[image]

And the lower image here:

[image]

Comment: thanks, that did the trick.